# Restrict to use IE in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I am developing intranet website in asp.net(mixed of MVC and Webform). So here I need to restrict the user to use IE &  chrome browser.

When User use IE, I should show some information say ***"website cannot be viewed in IE/Chrome***" and should not allow to browse further.

Can anyone help me ?

Comment: It's a bad design to actually restrict what browser you can use. Instead, you might show a warning saying something like "You are using <browser X>. This website was designed for <browser Y> and <browser Z>. To ensure compatibility, it's recommended that you use one of these browsers."

Comment: Ideally, you should use feature detection instead of browser detection. See [Browser and feature detection: Make your website look great everywhere](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/hh561717.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

in page load use this code to detect IE

```
System.Web.HttpBrowserCapabilities browser = Request.Browser;
string name = browser.Browser;
float version = (float)(browser.MajorVersion + browser.MinorVersion);
 if (name == "IE")
    {
            // show message, 
string message = "alert('You are using IE !')";
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock((sender as Control), this.GetType(), "alert", message, true);
return;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

That depends on a simple condition, you can use the Browser property of the Request that was started by the user. For example

```
if(Request.Browser.Browser == "IE") {
   // stop him from browsing, 
}
```

This is a single check for the Internet Explorer and will be applied to all the Internet Explorer versions.

Or as per MSDN, there is a better way for detecting the Browser using CSS, JavaScript or ASP.NET. Have a look here, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537509(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. I got solution... But Where Should I put the C# code to redirect the Parge ?

Comment: In the start of your .cshtml page. :) Or any where, where you're loading other C# server-side code.

Comment: I am looking event in global.asax file. Because in my application I  have MVC and webform also. Like Begin_request but still finding.

Comment: Add it anywhere, mostly in the beginning to stop any other code execution if the browser is IE.